# How to get value pairs from two different tables that don't have a relation in a third table?

Tags: sql

How to get value pairs (personID from Person table - vehicleID from Vehicle) that dont have a relation in a third table (HasLicence)

Person table:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ID  ║ FirstName  ║ LastName  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ Joe        ║ Smith     ║
║     2 ║ Tom        ║ Cage      ║
║     3 ║ Eric       ║ Hay       ║
║     4 ║ John       ║ Doe       ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Vehicle table:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ID  ║ Brand      ║ PlateNr   ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ Ford       ║ 111       ║
║     2 ║ BMW        ║ 222       ║
║     3 ║ BMW        ║ 333       ║
║     4 ║ Honda      ║ 444       ║
║     5 ║ Ford       ║ 555       ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

HasLicence table:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ID  ║ VehicleID  ║ PersonID  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ 1          ║ 1         ║
║     2 ║ 2          ║ 2         ║
║     3 ║ 3          ║ 3         ║
║     4 ║ 3          ║ 1         ║
║     5 ║ 4          ║ 1         ║
║     6 ║ 5          ║ 2         ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

For every PlateNr I need to list all the persons that dont have the license for that specific car.

I tried to create this results:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║   ID  ║ VehicleID  ║ PersonID  ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ 1          ║ 1         ║
║  null ║ 1          ║ 2         ║
║  null ║ 1          ║ 3         ║
║  null ║ 1          ║ 4         ║
║  null ║ 2          ║ 1         ║
║     2 ║ 2          ║ 2         ║
║  null ║ 2          ║ 3         ║
║  null ║ 2          ║ 4         ║
║     3 ║ 3          ║ 1         ║
║  null ║ 3          ║ 2         ║
║     4 ║ 3          ║ 3         ║
║  null ║ 3          ║ 4         ║
║     5 ║ 4          ║ 1         ║
...
```

This case I would be able to filter on all the rows that has no ID to get the value pairs. But I was not able to create such a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `cross join` of `Person` and `Vehicle` and `left join` to `HasLicence`:

```
select
  h.id, v.id VehicleID, p.id PersonID
from Person p cross join Vehicle v
left join HasLicence h
on h.personid = p.id and h.vehicleid = v.id
order by v.id, p.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orVqQKvrhuCVREz7DRv8BD/1).
Results:

```
| id  | VehicleID | PersonID |
| --- | --------- | -------- |
| 1   | 1         | 1        |
|     | 1         | 2        |
|     | 1         | 3        |
|     | 1         | 4        |
|     | 2         | 1        |
| 2   | 2         | 2        |
|     | 2         | 3        |
|     | 2         | 4        |
| 4   | 3         | 1        |
|     | 3         | 2        |
| 3   | 3         | 3        |
|     | 3         | 4        |
| 5   | 4         | 1        |
|     | 4         | 2        |
|     | 4         | 3        |
|     | 4         | 4        |
|     | 5         | 1        |
| 6   | 5         | 2        |
|     | 5         | 3        |
|     | 5         | 4        |
```

If you want only the rows *that don't have the license* then you need a `where` clause before the `order by` clause:

```
where h.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all combinations of persons and vehicles. That's a cross join. Then outer join the third table:

```
select *
from person p
cross join vehicle v
left outer join haslicence l on l.personid = p.id and l.vehicleid = v.id
order by l.personid, l.vehicleid;
```